# Change custom post title before publishing

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post named `session` where there are some custom fields such as `date`, and `event_location`.

I want to generate a title for this custom post, with the following code :

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'modify_post_title' , '99', 2 );

function modify_post_title( $data , $postarr )
{
  if($data['post_type'] == 'session') {

  //the id of the post
  $post_id = $postarr['ID'];

  //the date
  $date = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'session_date', true );

  //the location
  $event_location = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'session_location', true );

  //concatenating location and date
  $data['post_title'] = "$event_location-$date";
  }

  //returning the data
  return $data;
}
```

In order to make it work, i.e. in order to have a properly "forged" title used as a permalink (such as www.mysite.com/session/toronto-04282016), here is what I must do :

- create a new session and fill the required custom fields
- save it as a draft
- reload the page where the session was edited
- publish the session post

If I try to publish directly the custom post, its permalink takes the #id of the post such as : www.mysite.com/session/432.

EDIT : and the custom post title is empty

EDIT #2 : in the admin panel, if I click on update for a "directly published" custom post, its permalink and title take the "correct" form.

How can I do to be able to publish a new session with a custom title without using the draft step ?

Maybe the filter is not called when a custom post "session" is published. How can I force it to be called ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permalink inside `wp_insert_post_data` using the `post_name` parameter (which is the page slug) like this (the following use the [`sanitize_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) function to generate a valid permalink from post title):

```
$data['post_name'] = sanitize_title($data['post_title']);
```

Comment: thanks, I added this piece of code, but I still have the same problem : if I directly publish the session, the permalink is the id, and only the id. The title is still empty.

Comment: Is it just the permalink display in admin that is incorrect, or you can't access the post with the generated permalink at all?

Comment: I still can access the post with a permalink which has this form : www.mysite.com/session/432/

Comment: And if you try with the slug (do some `var_dump` to get the generated slug on `wp_instert_post_data`), does it give you a 404?